# Java Interface implements Object?

Tags: java

Does any Java Interface implicitly implements java.lang.Object?

This question arose when I did something like this:

```
public static String[] sizeSort(String[] sa) {

Comparator<String> c = new Comparator<String>() {
            public int compare(String a, String b) {
                if (a.length() > b.length()) return 1; 
                else if (a.length() < b.length())
                    return -1;
                else 
                    return 0;
                 }
        };

// more code

}
```

It worked fine even though I did not implement equals method of this interface.
Your answers clears this up. But does any one know if above is anonymous local inner class or named local inner class?

Comment: It's an anonymous inner class since it has no name.

Comment: While there are some nice answers below, consider this: `class X {}` -- there was no need to define a `equals`; why? The same holds true for anonymous classes that *implement* an interface: *all* class declarations that don't explicitly *extend* another class implicitly *extend* Object (thus all classes, either directly or indirectly, *extend* Object).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sort of. Citing the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.4.4):

> If an interface has no direct
>   superinterfaces, then **the interface
>   implicitly declares a public abstract
>   member method** m with signature s,
>   return type r, and throws clause t
>   **corresponding to each public instance
>   method** m with signature s, return type
>   r, and throws clause t **declared in
>   Object**, unless a method with the same
>   signature, same return type, and a
>   compatible throws clause is explicitly
>   declared by the interface. It is a compile-time error if the interface explicitly 
>   declares such a method m in the case
>   where m is declared to be final in
>   Object.

Note that `Object` has a number of final and protected methods that all interfaces "inherit" this way, and you couldn't have those modifiers in an interface (which would be implied by your "implements java.lang.Object").

Comment: +1 Interesting excerpt/find. I did not know that the JLS "promoted" the Object-contract to interfaces. I would guess this is explicitly specified to be able to discuss "shadowing" of such methods.

Comment: +1 That is interesting, it does make sense as well, otherwise how could you call hashCode on an interface?

Answer (score 6):

java.lang.Object is not an interface, so no interface will implicitly implement it.

However, any class that you create which implements any interface will extend Object, because all classes must extend it. Any instance which you (or indeed anyone else) can create will therefore have all of the methods defined on java.lang.Object.

Answer (score 2):

`Object` is a class, not an interface, so it can't be "implemented" by other interfaces.

The whole point of an interface is that it contains no implementation details.  If an interface could extend a class, it would inherit that class's implementation details, which would defeat the point.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking: How would you know the difference?
You will never have a reference to an interface, you will always having a reference to an actual instance with is an `Object` and implements the interface. This means that you can call methods from `Object` on any reference (not `null` of course) even if the declared type of the reference is an interface.

Comment: But the declared type of your reference can be an interface, so how come you can call equals() on it when that's not part of the interface?

Comment: Because Java knows it is an `Object` also?

Comment: This question appears to be about how exactly Java "knows" that.