# Overriding Object class methods within an interface in Java

Tags: java

Let's consider the following simple code in Java.

```java
package temppkg;

interface Interface
{
    @Override
    public abstract boolean equals(java.lang.Object arg);

    @Override
    public abstract String toString();

    public void show();
}

final class Demo implements Interface
{
    public void show()
    {
        System.out.println("Method invoked.");
    }
}

final public class Main
{
    public static void main(String...args)
    {
        new Demo().show();
    }
}
```

In the above code snippet, the interface  named `Interface` has some Object class methods from JDK and they are with the `@Override` annotation even though they are **abstract**. Now, the class `Demo` has implemented `Interface` and has **not** implemented the `equals()` and  the `toString();` methods. Still the compiler doesn't complain and the program is running successfully. Why?
What is the relation between interfaces and the object class in Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629685/java-interface-implements-object

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The Java Language Specification clearly says that the members of an
>   interface are those which are declared in the interface and those
>   which are inherited from direct super interfaces. If an interface has
>   no direct superinterface then the interface implicitly declares a
>   public abstract member method corresponding to each public instance
>   method declared in the Object class, unless a method with the same
>   signature, same return type, and a compatible throws clause is
>   explicitly declared by that interface. This is what makes the
>   signatures of the Object methods available to the compiler and the
>   code compiles without any error. Remember if the interface tries to
>   declare a public instance method declared 'final' in the Object class
>   then it'll result into a compile-time error. For example, 'public
>   final Class getClass()' is a public instance method declared 'final'
>   in the Object class and therefore if an interface tries to declare a
>   method with this signature then the compilation will fail.

http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2008/06/do-interfaces-really-inherit-from-class.html

Comment: Nice explanation, can you please share the exact specification url of Oracle's official website ?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [JLS 9.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html):

> If an interface has no direct superinterfaces, then the interface implicitly declares a public abstract member method *m* with signature *s*, return type *r*, and throws clause *t* corresponding to each public instance method *m* with signature *s*, return type *r*, and `throws` clause *t* declared in `Object`, unless a method with the same signature, same return type, and a compatible `throws` clause is explicitly declared by the interface. It is a compile-time error if the interface explicitly declares such a method *m* in the case where *m* is declared to be `final` in `Object`.

In other words, every interface implicitly defines each of `Object`'s methods, and you can therefore `@Override` those methods. The other methods aren't defined in `Object`, so you can't override them.

Answer (score 1):

In `Interface` you're not actually *overriding* anything - an interface by definition can not provide implementations for any of its methods. The class `Demo` just inherits the `equals` and `toString` implementation from `Object`.

In essence an interface in Java contains a set of zero or more method signatures (all of them are implicitly abstract, in your code you made it explicit by adding the keyword `abstract`), and the concrete classes that implement the interface must provide an implementation for those methods. In the case of your code, that implementation comes from `Object`, since all the classes implicitly extend `Object`, which provides default implementations for `equals` and `toString` (among other methods).

You really shouldn't mark the methods in an interface with `@Override`, as you have seen, it's confusing and serves for no practical purpose. Instead, use `@Override` in the methods in the concrete class that implement the methods of the interface, like this:

```
class Demo implements Interface {
    @Override
    public void show() {
        System.out.println("Method invoked.");
    }
}
```

Also, it's completely unnecessary to declare `equals` and `toString` in an interface, so you're better off with this definition:

```
interface Interface {
    public void show();
}
```

Comment: An attempt to annotate  other methods with `@Override` within an interface issues a compile-time error. How? This is the actual question.

Comment: I know that it has no practical importance but why does actually this happen?

Comment: Of course it issues a compile-time error, as I've stated in my answer, you _can not_ provide an implementation for a method in an interface, when you mark a method with @Override you're saying that you're going to implement it

Comment: The OP is saying that it issues a compile-time error when he uses the annotation on a method not implemented by Object. But no error happens when he uses it on methods such as equals() and toString().

Comment: OK, that's weird. Maybe the compiler simply ignores those methods in an interface, given that they already exist in every object in Java

Answer (score 0):

`@Override` can only be used for functions defined in the base class, Object. Object defines `equals` and `toString`, so you can use `@Override` with them, but not with, say, the function show. It indicates a relationship between the `@Override` functions in a class and its base classes, not it's derived classes.

Comment: What's that ***bade class***?

Comment: must be base class. I think it's a typo